# "Exception ignored in:" message in a loop

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.4

I transferred my code from Python2.7 to Python3.4 with changes replaced from reading from csv to reading from database and few more. I keep on getting a message "Exception Ignored in:" when I run the app. What could be the issue or how can I trace it since Exception ignored in message does not provide more info. I also encounter this message when I press Ctrl-C. I found that the error occurs when I assign a class instance as a value to a dictionary. But I am not sure what the error is.

This is the message that I get:

```
Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in:
```

Comment: Please post the **complete traceback message** and also explain why you have tagged it with [tag:django]

Comment: I am running this as part of django rest framework. Hence the tag.

Comment: That can't be the complete message; usually on an error there is some traceback. Try running with DEBUG=True on a test environment.

Comment: I did that too. But when I press Ctrl-C I get this message.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Looks like this is a known problem. https://bugs.python.org/issue22836
Not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: What is the exact Python version?

Comment: Python 3.4.0 is the version

Comment: Any idea how to rectify it?